Strange memory leak in simple C queue implementation
I am trying to add a simple linked queue with enqueue() and dequeue() functions to my C library.
In all tests, the queue seems to perform as expected, without any errors. However, when testing for memory leaks by appending 200 million elements and then popping them, the memory doesn't seem to get freed, yet the list updates correctly.
enqueue() and dequeue() functions:
usf_queue *usf_enqueue(usf_queue *queue, usf_data d) {
    //Enqueue to FIFO queue
    if (queue == NULL) {
        //Generate new queue
        queue = (usf_queue *) malloc(sizeof(usf_queue));

        if (queue == NULL) return NULL; //Memory allocation failure

        //Empty at first
        queue -> first = queue -> last = NULL;
    }   

    usf_queuenode *append = (usf_queuenode *) malloc(sizeof(usf_queuenode));

    if (append == NULL) return NULL; //Memory allocation failure

    append -> data = d;
    append -> next = NULL; //Last in line

    if (queue -> last == NULL) //Was empty
        queue -> first = queue -> last = append;
    else { //Normal adding
        queue -> last -> next = append;
        queue -> last = append;
    }

    return queue;
}

usf_data usf_dequeue(usf_queue *queue) {
    //Dequeue from FIFO queue
    usf_data d;
    usf_queuenode *old;

    if (queue -> first == NULL || queue == NULL)
        return (usf_data) { .p = NULL }; //No queue, or queue is empty

    old = queue -> first;
    d = old -> data; //Get data

    if ((queue -> first = old -> next) == NULL)
        queue -> last = NULL;

    free(old); //Destroy dequeued node
    return d;
}

Queue structures :
typedef union usf_data {
    void *p; 
    uint64_t u;
    int64_t i;
} usf_data;

typedef struct usf_queuenode {
    usf_data data;
    struct usf_queuenode *next;
} usf_queuenode;

typedef struct usf_queue {
    usf_queuenode *first;
    usf_queuenode *last;
} usf_queue;

And, finally, the test code :
#include "usflib2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    usf_queue *q = NULL;
    q = usf_enqueue(q, (usf_data) {.u = -1 }); 

    for (int i = 1; i < 200000000; i++)
        usf_enqueue(q, (usf_data) {.u = i});

    printf("Done.\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
        usf_dequeue(q);
    }   

    free(q);
    printf("Finished\n");
    for(;;);
    return 0;
}


"However, when testing for memory leaks by appending 200 million elements and then popping them, the memory doesn't seem to get freed," How exactly do you determine this? Specify in your question. Are you using an actual memory leak detector, such as valgrind? Or are you making the same mistake I and many others have and looking at a system administration tool that is reporting memory checked out to a process, which is largely useless and often misleading when checking for memory leaks? (I haven't read your code yet.)

On top of system tools reporting 6G being still allocated, I have tried starting a second process of the program after the first one's deallocation is "complete". Instead of using the supposedly free memory, it allocates on top of it, leading to one getting killed by the OS because of memory shortage.

Doesn't sound like you've etablished a leak. What does valgrind say, or running a build build with -fsanitize=address.

Just because a program internally frees dynamically memory, that does not mean that the memory is returned to the operation system. The program is allowed to retain the memory internally for future use. This is not necessarily visible to system tools. System tools are generally the wrong tools to check for memory leaks. You need insturmentaion specifically for memory leaks. Nothing you've observed seems to be a definitive indication of a memory leak. I've read your code now, and haven't spotted a memory leak. (I'm not comfortable with your usf_data type, but that is another matter.)

I've just tried using valgrind. According to it, there is no memory leak, however the program clearly doesn't free() in the way I understand it; even after it has "freed" the memory nothing else seems to be able to use it. Does a program need to exit before its free() calls take effect ?

Instead of using the supposedly free memory, it allocates on top of it, leading to one getting killed by the OS because of memory shortage.  The processes would never use each other's memory — their memory allocations are completely separate.  The freed memory is freed so that the process that allocated it can reuse the space, but it is not freed so that other processes can use it.  You'd have to take charge of memory allocation using, for example, mmap() — then you could release slabs of allocated memory back to the o/s.

Your usf_enqueue() function should take a reference to usf_queue *. The usf_queue you allocated in usf_enqueue() function was not returned back to the caller. Basically, every time you call usf_enqueue(), you create a new usf_queue.

@yty This is C, there are no references. And  usf_enqueue()  does return the  usf_queue and it is saved in main the first time it is called. Maybe not the cleanest, but it works here.

In main(), print out 'q' right after the first call to usf_enqueue() and see if it is still NULL.

free() is free for reuse, but not necessarily free and release back to the operating system. The memory management library may choose to retain it inside the program for reuse within that program for future allocations. If it does this, it may not be released to the OS until program exit.

@yty Done. It isn't. "0x502000000010 Not NULL" https://godbolt.org/z/rbTqGvnTW Note the assignment of the return value for the first call. If the return value were ignored as it is later, it would behave as you expected.

@AviBerger Thank you for your answers, I have just one more question. You mentioned that my usf_data type and usf_enqueue also serving as a constructor may not be good practice, but what would you suggest instead ? Especially for the former, as I want to avoid having three copies of usf_queue for each data type.

My issues with usf_data are first with there being no way of determining which is the active member. It may be that in a larger context than your post this is resolved. Secondly, if it is the void * member that is in use and it is used to own dynamically allocated memory, then  use of usf_dequeue would produce a bonafide memory leak when used in this manner

Not sure what to say about usf_enqueue. It's constuctor like extra functionality isn't obvious, could be misleading, and has probably contributed to yty's issue here. People who are strict about "separation of concerns" will object to it and do have a point. I would probably use a separate init() function for usf_queue, though I don't think I'd make that big a fuss over it.

@AviBerger You are right. Thanks.

Have a look into the sanitizers coming with clang for example. There you can test for memory leaks much more efficient.

It seems the 'leak' was actually caused by my misunderstanding of the C free() function.
I thought freed memory was made available to the OS, and other processes, but it seems that it stays locked into the process who first allocated it (at least, on my computer, the system prefers crashing than retaking freed memory).
EDIT: as pointed out by Avi Berger, this behavior is dependent on the program's own memory management libraries.

It is not the OS's choice, It can't really retake the memory unless it kills the program. It depends on the memory management implementation used in the program that determines this behavior. Trade off of releasing memory back to the OS vs having it at hand for future allocations in the program without the overhead of going back to the OS to fetch it again. C library implementations vary in how they handle this.

Memory leak
There is memory leak potential, even if it does not fully account for OP's woes.
Consider what happens when code returns due to if (append == NULL) return NULL;.  If that allocation was the first data of the queue, then the prior queue = (usf_queue *) malloc(sizeof(usf_queue)); allocation is lost.

Undefined behavior (UB)
With usf_dequeue(usf_queue *queue) and queue == NULL, code attempts queue -> first which is UB.
To fix, change:
// if (queue -> first == NULL || queue == NULL)
if (queue == NULL || queue -> first == NULL)


Weak test
Rather than ignore the return value, it should be tested.
for (int i = 1; i < 200000000; i++)
  // usf_enqueue(q, (usf_data) {.u = i});
  if (usf_enqueue(q, (usf_data) {.u = i}) == NULL) {
    TBD(); //Do something.
  }

Same for q = usf_enqueue(q, (usf_data) {.u = -1 });.
usf_dequeue(q); should also test the data returned to see if it is the value expected.

Conclusion
I suggest to fix these issues and see if the improved code behaves more understandably.

Thank you for your suggestions. For the potential memory leak, that can only happen if malloc() errors the second time (at allocating 8 bytes). This is catastrophic error as I understand it, and the program should exit anyways. As for UB: thanks, I did not notice that. Also, I did do more extensive tests (print outs and such), but kept it simpler for the case of this problem.

@Analyzers The 2nd allocation is more than 8 bytes.   "can only happen" case is inside a for (int i = 1; i < 200000000; i++) loop.  "As for UB: .... I did not notice that"  --> UB can be subtle.  It may affect the memory doesn't seem to get freed rendering conclusions moot.  "kept it simpler for the case of this problem"  --> IMO, it is now too simply and needs added error checking.  Best to post a [mcve].
